# Background del tamaño de pantalla con scroll

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Tengo un código que he recopilado desde distintos sitios de ejemplos. La idea es hacer una imagen inicial que sea del tamaño de la pantalla con un menú despegable. Todo funciona pero lamentablemente no puedo hacer scroll en la imagen.

```css
body {
        background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1920/1080/?random');
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:center center;
        background-attachment:scroll;
        -o-background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
        -moz-background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
        -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
        background-size: 100% 100%, auto; 
    }
    .wrap { 
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:column;
        min-height:100vh;
    }
    .fixed-top.scrolled {
        background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1) !important;
        box-shadow:0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16),0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
        animation:animatetop 0.4s}@keyframes animatetop{from{top:-300px;opacity:0} to{top:0;opacity:}
    }   
    .wrap {  
        color: black;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>   
    <div class="wrap">        
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top nav" id="myNavbar"> 
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Menu</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Menu de Navegacion"> 
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"><i class="fa fa-navicon"></i></span> 
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a href="#" class="nav-link">TITLE 1</a> </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a href="#" class="nav-link">TITLE 2</a> </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a href="#" class="nav-link">TITLE 3</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>    
    </div> 
    <section id="services">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="display-4">Services.. here is some more content</h1>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="display-4">Here is some more content</h1>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="display-4">Here is some more content</h1>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-zDnhMsjVZfS3hiP7oCBRmfjkQC4fzxVxFhBx8Hkz2aZX8gEvA/jsP3eXRCvzTofP" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  
    <script>
        $(document).scroll(function () {
            $(".fixed-top").toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() >  $(".fixed-top").height());
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que no puedes hacer scroll sobre la imagen? ¿quieres que la imagen quede fija mientras haces scroll?

Comment: Ya lo solucioné, era un problema de etiquetas css. Cambié la etiqueta body por otra etiqueta y dejé fuera las demás etiquetas css en el archivo html